# PrimeNg GlobalFilter : Stop searching after finding match in first column (Not looking for values in subsequent columns)

Tags: angular, primeng, treetable, primeng-treetable, global-filter

**Initial UI (Without filter):**

```
[globalFilterFields]="['name','marketingName','m_id']"
```

[image: Initial UI]

**Issue : Other column fields are skipped after match found in first column**

Here, we are searching "Model" which is present in first as well as in second column. But, it's not considering second column.

[image]

**Expectations** : first 3 rows should be shown that are Database, Dataset1, Model

**Stackblitz** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablefilter-demo-efg4b5?file=src/assets/filesystem.json

Kindly expand module and then search using "Model" in global search.

We have search box to filter rows of p-treeTable by using global filter as shown below :

```
<input #searchBox type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" pInputText class="searchBox"
          placeholder="Search"
          (input)="tt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" />
```

Column Definition mapped to TreeTable looks like below:

```
this.columns = [
      { field: "name", header: "Name", width: '38%' },
      { field: "marketingName", header: "marketingName", width: '19%' },
      { field: "m_id", header: "M ID", width: '16%' },
      { field: "operation", header: "Operation", width: '7%' }
    ];
```

TreeTable Code:

```
<p-treeTable #tt [value]="businessUnit" [columns]="columns" selectionMode="single"
          [(selection)]="selectedTreeProgram" dataKey="name" (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect(true)"
          (onNodeUnselect)="onNodeSelect(false)" [globalFilterFields]="['name','marketingName','m_id']">
          <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
            <colgroup>
              <col *ngFor="let col of columns" [style.width]="col.width">
            </colgroup>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let col of columns" style="display: none">
                {{col.header}}
              </th>
            </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
            <tr class="bu-row" [id]="utils.getId(rowData['name'])">
              <td *ngIf="!rowData['m_id']"> 
                  <div class="combine name">{{rowData['name']}}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                //Dummy
              </td>
              <td>
                //Dummy
              </td>
              <td>
                //Dummy
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="rowData['m_id']" [ttRow]="rowNode" [ttSelectableRow]="rowNode" class="tree-child-row">
              <td>
                   //Icons
                  <div class="combine name">{{rowData['name']}}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="combine">{{rowData['marketingName']}}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="combine">{{rowData['m_id']}}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                    //Edit Delete Icon
              </td>
            </tr>
          </ng-template>
        </p-treeTable>
```

Comment: Can you add sample data for businessUnit

Comment: Please find below Stacklitz URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablefilter-demo-efg4b5?file=src/assets/filesystem.json . Expand Module and in global search, please search using "Model"